# Clear list of Complex object Type

Tags: ibm-bpm

I have a search function in my application which gets me customers. Therefore I got an complex "Customer" object. So the list is of type Customer.

This list is filled properly on button click. But when I want to clear the list on Button click a error is thrown in my browser console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What is the correct way to clear a list of complex object? Currently I am using a General Service which does the following:

```
tw.local.searchResults = new tw.object.listOf.Customer();
```

This throws me the above error.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please share the code. Where are you checking length.

Answer (score 1):

Do a check on the length of the list such as *if its length is not undefined* and then read the results inside the if-block.